# Site search in asp .net application

Tags: .net, asp.net, search

May I know what are the best practices for implementing a site search in ASP .net web app. The user should be able to enter some keywords and get related links with the keyword. I have just started researching. It would be great if you put  on your ideas.

Comment: How is the data you want to search stored, database?

Comment: Well this is a good question. But what should I be storing in the database? The keywords and the corresponding URLs or what?

Comment: Well what is it you want the user to be able to search for?

Comment: The User should be able to search for a specific content within a page. Say for instance there is a web page that contains words say "HR Policies". So when the user searches for this keyword in say the main page of the website. he should be presented with links to the pages that contains "HR Policies"

Comment: I am guessing then that you aren't using a CMS and this is static pages? If so then other have already answered, and what you are looking for is a web crawler. If you don't want to implement one your self, you can always use google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on where your data is stored: database or static pages.

For the former, I'd use Lucene.NET (check out the SubText blog in which the latest release has a good implementation). For the latter I'd use dtSearch to crawl the site to create an index which you can search across.

Answer (score 2):

If its a small public site, you're better off using Google as your search engine with their [Custom Search engine](http://www.google.com/cse/) program.

This isn't an option with an internal site that Google can't see, obviously.  If your content is in a database, I've heard good things about [Lucine](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/).  SQL Server 2008's Full Text search features work rather well, too, if you're on that platform.  I think that's what SO uses for its search.  Or Jeff played with it at one point and had good things to say.  Don't know if they're still using it.

Comment: If you do have an internal site, you can always purchase a Google Search Appliance (http://www.google.com/enterprise/search/gsa.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using database for storing the content, you can use SQL Server Full Text Search Language functionality which is containing bunch of tables and then you can search against that. We used to this approach before.

See for more detail: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-full-text-search-language-features/

Answer (score 0):

Here is C# Code

```cs
protected void OnPaging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView2.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    this.Searchmyform();
}

protected void Search(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Searchmyform();
}

private void Searchmyform()
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM [test].[dbo].[myform]";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearch.Text.Trim()))
        {
            sql += "  where name like '" + txtSearch.Text + "%' or contact like '" + txtSearch.Text + "%'" +
                   " or email like '" + txtSearch.Text + "%' ";
        }

        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            GridView2.DataSource = dt;
            GridView2.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Aspx code is such that

```html
<div class="topnav card-body">
    <div class="search-container-lg float-right">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server"
                  OnTextChanged="Search"
                  AutoPostBack="true"
                  placeholder="Search.."
                  CssClass="">
        </asp:TextBox>
...
```